# How to Secure Grpc Server and Client over .NET framework

Tags: ssl-certificate, client-server, grpc, .net-4.8

I am working on purely .NET Framework platform only. I have made a gRPC client and server which communicate with each other but in an insecure way. I wanted to establish a secure connection with SSL certificates but all the methods require using .NET Core platform(but I am strictly on .NET Framework). Can I make the server secure in some way and connect using a Client?

The following is a small listener that I have for my service:-

```
class GrpcCommunicationListener: ICommunicationListener
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<ServerServiceDefinition> _services;
        private readonly Uri _endpointAddress;
        private Server _server;

        public async Task<string> OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var port = _endpointAddress.Port;
            var host = _endpointAddress.Host;

            try
            {
                _server = new Server
                {
                    Ports = { new ServerPort(host, port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
                };
                foreach (var service in _services)
                {
                    _server.Services.Add(service);
                }
                _server.Start();
                return $"http://{host}:{port}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                await StopServerAsync();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate any help as I am strictly coupled to .NET Framework and would like to know a way out as all the servers that I have seen till now have needed the .NET Core libraries.
Or if there is no way then please let me know.

Comment: If you're strictly tied to the legacy .NET Framework, you can still use Grpc.Core (which fully supports .NET Framework): https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/csharp But you also need to be aware that in the future we plan to deprecate Grpc.Core in favor of grpc-dotnet: see blogpost https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-csharp-future/

Comment: We are planning to provide some level of grpc-dotnet support on .NET Framework, but it's going to be for client side only and it's not fully ready yet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#net-grpc-client-requirements